# How does "data.map(Result.success)" work and Return a type of Result<Data, Error>?

Tags: swift, foundation

I stumbled upon the following piece of code in [this tutorial](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/constructing-urls-in-swift) and I cannot figure out how the return value of *data.map(Result.success)* works.

So far, I knew .map to work with $0 in the closure. In this case, only *Result.success* is provided. How is the return value of this call of type `Result<Data, Error>`?

```
class DataLoader {
    func request(_ endpoint: Endpoint,
             then handler: @escaping (Result<Data, NError>) -> Void) {
        guard let url = endpoint.url else {
            return handler(.failure(NError.invalidURL))
        }

        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: url) {
            data, _, error in

            let result = data.map(Result.success) ??
                .failure(NError.network)

            handler(result)
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` you are seeing here is not the `map` that is usually called on arrays/sequences that transforms each element into something else. It is [`Optional.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map).

`map` in this case does this:

- if the optional has a value, transforms the value wrapped inside the optional using the closure, and returns the transformed value wrapped in an optional.
- if the optional is nil, returns nil.

In your code, `let result = data.map(Result.success) ?? .failure(NError.network)` can thus be rewritten like this:

```
let result: Result<Data, Error>
if data == nil {
    result = .failure(NError.network)
} else {
    result = Result.success(data!)
}
```

As you can see `Result.success` is passed as a function here. If you are used to seeing the `$0` syntax, here's how it will look if it were written with `$0`:

```
data.map { Result.success($0) }
```

Comment: An interesting point is that `data` is optional yet you call `map` without a need for `?` like you normally would.

Comment: Just for further understanding: The variable result is type inferred to be Result<Data, Error> from the "data.map(Result.success)" and therefore I have to add "?? .failure(Error.network)" to give as a choice in case "data == nil". I cannot simply leave that out to get a "nil" as return value for my variable result? Unless I change the line to "let result: Result<Data, NError>? = data.map(Result.success)"...

Comment: @ChrisGraf if I understand you correctly, you are right.